# Render html from display hook without template file

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I want to add a div with a specific id (later filled by some javascript) using a display hook.

I can create a dedicated tpl file, but it seems overkill: is there a way to render html programmatically from PHP module ? The below array could be provided to some rendering method:

```
array(
'div' => array(
    'id' => 'my-div-'.Tools::getValue('id_product')
))
```

I know there's a way to generate admin form this way using `HelperForm`. I'm wondering if this is doable for some random html in some random display hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use "echo" or directly return the html content as a string in display hooks but using the Tpl files is recommended.